# Frescobaldi does not create files

Tags: lilypond

I am using LilyPond with Frescobaldi editor. It sometimes happens that Frescobaldi stops working, that is: If I change something in the .ly file (e.g. some string) and hit the Lilypond button (or press CTRL+M), nothing happens. The preview does not update, and no files are generated/updated.

I use:

- Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon, Version 5.0.5, Linux Kernel 5.4.0-80-generic.
- GNU LilyPond 2.20.0.
- Frescobaldi Version 3.0.0.

Until now I managed to get rid of this problem by closing and reopening Frescobaldi, but it does not help any more. I even removed and reinstalled Frescobaldi, restarted my computer, removed the config file... but nothing helps. Frescobaldi just does not work anymore.

**Any ideas what I can do to make it work again?**

If not, I'd already be happy if someone can give a clue to what is going on here. Currently, this is just (evil) magic to me...

---

Here is a simple example LilyPond file `newFile.ly`:

```
\version "2.20.0"

title = "title"
music = { \relative { c' d e f g } }

\bookpart {
  \header {
    title = \title
  }
  \score {
    \music
    \layout { }
  }
}
```

If I run `lilypond newFile.ly` in the console, I get the following output in the console:

```
GNU LilyPond 2.20.0
Processing `newFile.ly'
Parsing...
Interpreting music...
Preprocessing graphical objects...
Finding the ideal number of pages...
Fitting music on 1 page...
Drawing systems...
Layout output to `/tmp/lilypond-NKnbRf'...
Converting to `newFile.pdf'...
Deleting `/tmp/lilypond-NKnbRf'...
Success: compilation successfully completed
```

A pdf is generated (or overwritten if already present).

If I open `newFile.ly` in Frescobaldi, change the string value of `title` to `"title2"`, save and then press  CTRL+M, I get this:

[image]

No preview window is opened, no pdf is generated, and the Lilypond log inside Frescobaldi is suspiciously short: it contains only three entries (`Processing`, `Parsing`, `Success`), unlike the Lilypond log in the console after a direct `lilypond` call.

Before Frescobaldi stopped working, I always got a long log just like when using `lilypond` in the console.

I wonder: If Frescobaldi merely calls `lilypond` under the hood, why are all the other steps (`Interpreting`, `Preprocessing`, ...) omitted? And why were they not omitted before (when Frescobaldi still worked)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for the current "broken-ness":

If there is a file `init.ly` inside the folder of the main file (main file = the one to be compiled), console `lilypond` doesn't mind but Frescobaldi can't cope with it and will behave as described in the question. Even if that `init.ly` file isn't even `\include`d anywhere!

I guess this is worth a Frescobaldi bug report. Anyone who wants to do that - go ahead!

---

How did that happen?

I use `\include`, and I named one of the included files (which consists solely of variable assignments) `init.ly`. Didn't know that was a bad name choice. I went on working on my main file, and after I added the `\include "init.ly"` statement and compiled with console `lilypond`, the error message there

> /usr/share/lilypond/2.20.0/ly/init.ly:43:1: error: \maininput not
> allowed outside init files

made me suspicious, so I renamed my `init.ly` file and voila, Frescobaldi was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a Frescobaldi problem but a misunderstanding about LilyPond include files and Frescobaldi's include paths (Edit -> Preferences -> LilyPond Preferences tab at the bottom).

There already is a file called `init.ly` in LilyPond.  Depending on how your include paths are setup, you may get this file or the file you created.  If you get LilyPond's `init.ly` file, then things go haywire.

Notice your error message:

> /usr/share/lilypond/2.20.0/ly/init.ly:43:1: error: \maininput not allowed outside init files

See that you are including LilyPond's `init.ly` file, not yours.  If you include the full path of the file, the problem goes away:

```
include "/full/path/to/your/init.ly"
```

Comment: If I have a file of a certain name `X` in the same folder as the file that I'm compiling (and I'm NOT including `X` in the main file!), and I use `lilypond` compiler, there is no problem at all. It just does not matter that `X` is there. That is, in my opinion, the correct behaviour. Frescobaldi on the other hand DOES care about the presence of `X`: It simply does not compile. How can this not be a Frescobaldi issue?

Comment: Well, the comments of StackExchange are too small for me you post examples.  The long and the short of it is, I don't get the behavior you're seeing with my test files.  Why don't we pickup the conversation on the [Frescobaldi discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/frescobaldi)?

Comment: I created a post in the Frescobaldi discussion group [here](https://groups.google.com/g/frescobaldi/c/UrCZZEGR0Yk) that explains what I did.  You may be asked to formal join the group -- it's been so long since I first posted there I forget.

Comment: Don't want to join google groups, sorry. But you didn't do what I did. Here's what you should check: Create `foo.ly` file without any includes. It should be compilable (i.e. have no errors). Create `init.ly` file in the same folder. It can contain anything you want, or stay empty. Then compile `foo.ly` with command line `lilypond`. There shouldn't be any issues. Now open `foo.ly` in Frescobaldi and compile from there. Does it compile and generate pdf? Or do you only get the short log of just three entries (`Processing`, `Parsing`, `Success`)? If the latter, then you have reproduced my issue.

Comment: Following your instructions, I get no errors with LilyPond at the command line nor with Frescobaldi.